why counter"libjuicity exits too fast" error when wanted to connect an access key via NekoBox?
I created a juicy access key on a server by using this command on the server.
bash <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deathline94/Juicity-Installer/main/juicity-installer.sh)

When I wanted to use it in NekoBox, I encountered this error: "libjuicity exits too fast" (exit code: 1).
4 months ago, I used to create the same access key and conveniently used it and could connect successfully through filtered webpages.
server VPN
Does anyone have any idea what the reason for this error is?

I realized that the issue stemmed from the settings. I should have enabled "allow insecure"..., but now the access key does not connect and the error message has changed to a "time out" error..

you can try to use husi instead. it's having support of juicity without the question you've mentioned.
